# How to redirect to invoice menu from Odoo website?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I am working on odoo11. I want to **redirect** to **Invoicing** menu from **Odoo website** on button click. How can I achieve it through code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using HTML for your website, You can use anchor tag:

```
<a href="http://www.your_invoice_menu_url">Invoice!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use controller to redirect website page to backend but make sure on your controller you use `auth=user` for security reason so public user can not go to backend.